# Remove point from list if within certain threshold of any other point

Tags: python, python-3.x, euclidean-distance

I have code that filters points from a list where the distance between them is below 3:

```
import numpy
lst_x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lst_y = [9,1,3,2,7,6,2,7,2,3,8]
lst = numpy.column_stack((lst_x,lst_y))

diff = 3

new = []
for n in lst:
    if not new or ((n[0] - new[-1][0]) ** 2 + (n[1] - new[-1][1]) ** 2) ** .5 >= diff:
    new.append(n)
```

The problem is that the output is:

```
[array([0, 9]), array([1, 1]), array([4, 7]), array([6, 2]), array([7, 7]), array([8, 2]), array([10,  8])]
```

point `[6,2]` and `[8,2]` are closer than 3 to each other yet they are in the results, I believe this is because the for loop is only checking one point then jumping to the next.

How can I make it check all numbers at every point.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm very carefully checks against *only* the point most recently added to the list, `new[-1]`.  This is insufficient.  You need another loop to make sure that you check against *each* element of `new`.  Something like this:

```
for n in lst:
    too_close = False
    for seen_point in new:  
        # Is any previous point too close to this one (n)?
        if not new or ((n[0] - seen_point[0]) ** 2 +     \
                       (n[1] - seen_point[1]) ** 2) ** .5 < diff:
            too_close = True
            break

    # If no point was too close, add this one to the "new" list.
    if not too_close:
        new.append(n)
```